# In grails how can I let the transactionManager is mongoTransactionManager?

Tags: mongodb, grails, transactionmanager

I use grails 2.0.1, and uninstall-plugin hibernate, install-plugin mongodb.
Now there is no bean named transactionManager, and there is a mongoTransactionManager.
So my question is how can I define the transactionManager in my resources.groovy?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that some form of transaction support is available, by using the following in your *Service* classes.

```
static transactional = 'mongo'
```

See Here: [Grails data mapping/mongo docs](http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/5.%20Transactions.html) and [GPMONGODB-9](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-9)

Otherwise, if (like me) you're using a plugin which requires transactional support (JAX-RS in my case) you can do the following.

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        grailsApplication.mainContext.registerAlias('mongoTransactionManager',
                                                    'transactionManager')
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to register aliases in resources.groovy, since the above won't work for singleton beans that need a transaction manager (since they are already constructed before BootStrap.init is run). Instead, in resources.groovy: beans = {
    springConfig.addAlias('transactionManager', 'mongoTransactionManager') }